# ggplot2 chage legend key from cross to line when using different geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have this code

```
library(tidyverse)
df=mammals
ggplot(df, aes(log(body))) +
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..density..)) +
  stat_function(fun = "dnorm",
                aes(color = "a",
                    linetype = "a")) +
  geom_vline(aes(
    xintercept = -4,
    color = "b",
    linetype = "b"
  )) +
  geom_vline(aes(
    xintercept = -3,
    color = "c",
    linetype = "b"
  )) +
  guides(linetype = FALSE)
```

which produces this plot:

[image]

However, I do not want there to be crosses. I would like to have there lines. In the best case they would be solid and dashed. I tried this, but had only partial success (I am also not really sure why I must in `overwrite.aes` put the `"b"` two times...):

```
library(tidyverse)
df = mammals
ggplot(df, aes(log(body))) +
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..density..)) +
  stat_function(fun = "dnorm",
                aes(color = "a",
                    linetype = "a")) +
  geom_vline(aes(
    xintercept = -4,
    color = "b",
    linetype = "b"
  )) +
  geom_vline(aes(
    xintercept = -3,
    color = "c",
    linetype = "b"
  )) +
  guides(linetype = FALSE, color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
    linetype = c("a" = "dashed", "b" = "solid", "b" = "solid")
  )))
```

However I do not know how to change the legend symbol to a line.

[image]

Comment: Does adding `show.legend = FALSE` within `stat_function()` to your plot do what you want or do you want horizontal instead of vertical lines? For changing the glyph in the legend see `key_glyph` in different geoms. I always have to check for what glyphs are available at `?draw_key`

Comment: yes!!:) Thank you very much! A simple `show.legend=FALSE` did the trick